# Button prevents KeyDown event from triggering even with keypreview = true

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-events

Steps to reproduce in VS Express 12:

- Create a new Windows Forms Application project
- Add a button
- Set the Form KeyPreview to true
- Add a keyDown event to the form
- The event will not trigger as long as the button is present on the form

I have a project where I want to catch both keydown and keyup events, however, I can only seem to get the keyup event to work.

I have a form with a single panel, button and label on it. In the form the keyPreview property is set to true, and is linked to both the KeyDown and KeyUp events.
However, when I run the program, only the KeyUp event triggers.

I tried adding the event handlers manually by adding

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
```

But it still does not work.

Any suggestions?

KeyUp event:

```
    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TriggerKey(e.KeyCode, false);
    }

    private void TriggerKey(Keys e, Boolean pKeyDown)
    {
        switch (e)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
                mLeft = pKeyDown;
                break;

            case Keys.Right:
                mRight = pKeyDown;
                break;

            case Keys.Down:
                mDown = pKeyDown;
                break;

            case Keys.Up:
                mUp = pKeyDown;
                break;
        }
    }
```

My Form1_KeyDown event looks like this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TriggerKey(e.KeyCode, true);
}
```

Edit2:
I've tried removing the button from my form, and then both events trigger correctly. If I add it back in, the keyDown event stops working again. Why is the button interfering when the keypreview property is set?

Comment: do any of your controls have focus? try clicking in the empty area of your form and pressing a key

Comment: Is this with Windows Forms or WPF? C# doesn't have a KeyDown event.

Comment: I tried that too, but if the focus was the problem, should KeyPreview fix it and keyUp shouldn't be fired?

Comment: @JohnSaunders This is with Windows Forms. Sorry if I was being a bit unclear. Is that the problem?

Comment: Updated the keyup event to make sense since so many were commenting it

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Great first question - in terms of provided information!

Comment: @Brian Thank you very much!
I've tried removing the button from my form, and then both events trigger correctly. Why is the button interfering when the keypreview property is set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeyPreview is a VB6 compatibility feature, it isn't "native" Winforms.  And it has a  problem that exactly matches your issue.  There are other Form methods that get a sniff at the keystroke first, before the code that looks at KeyPreview gets a chance to run and fire the KeyDown event.  And they eat the navigation keystrokes first.  Like the cursor keys that you are trying to see as well as the Tab key.  This matches the VB6 behavior, it also couldn't see the cursor keys.

To stay ahead of that code, you'll need to override the ProcessDialogKey() method of the form.  Like this:

```
    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData) {
        switch (keyData) {
            case Keys.Left:
                //...
                return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
```

Comment: That worked flawlessly, and thank you for elaborating! In this case it was true for all the keys and not just the directional ones. Is this considered a known bug?

Comment: This is not a bug, it is entirely by design.

Comment: I would say `This is not a bug, it's a feature` :)

Answer (score 0):

you're setting mUp on keyDown...? can you add all the related code context such as the mouse up event, also you may try to refresh, if you break does the even fire on key down?

Comment: There is no other events than KeyUp and KeyDown, I added the KeyUp event code now. Was there other pieces of code you wanted me to add in?

Comment: Welcome to SO, @BunnyStrider.  In the future, posts like yours are better suited as a comment and less as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that keyup is raised after keydown(if you want your mUp to remain true)

Comment: Fixed it to make sense now. Tho the KeyDown event still isn't firing.

Comment: But it will be false after pressing up arrow. How do you know the event doesn't work

Comment: Breakpoints and that I get it working correctly when I remove the button from my form.

Comment: If you read my question you would see that I have already set that property. Appreciate the effort tho

Answer (score 0):

I saw in other similar posts that this could help

```
this.focus();
```

give it a try and let me know to keep looking for other ways